# Matrix vertical space in top row when using \linespread{}

Tags: spacing, equations, matrices, setspace

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\linespread{3}
%\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0.85}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The above minimal example gives me (around the matrix):

[image]

The value in `\linespread{3}` is of course exaggerated and impractical but it emphasizes the problem.

#### The question

Is there a straightforward way to fix the spacing above the top row (1 2) in order to get a symmetric look of the matrix? Everything else should remain the same. I am aware of the effect of `\arraystretch` (see commented out line), which is not what I am aiming at.

#### Background

I am facing some vertical spacing issues with the package `setspace`. I considered some alleged solutions but am still unhappy with the result. But I think I can kind of boil the problem down to this question.

### Edit 2023-06-27: Additional information as requested

To my knowledge `setspace` does not a lot more than calculating a value for `\linespread{}` from some parameters like the fontsize and changes some other vertical spacing values, e.g., before and after equations. So the problem is exactly the same when using `setspace`, see the following minimal example.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% \linespread{3}
\usepackage{setspace}
% actually I'd like to use \onehalfspacing, but again,
% a bigger stretch makes the problem more clear
\setstretch{3} 

%\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0.85}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Here's again a screenshot showing the same problem:

[image]

Finally to the "alleged solutions":

- I have played around with `arraystretch` as mentioned before and it does the job to some degree. But this does not really resolve the symmetry that is at the heart of this issue.
- I tried to switch to `singlespacing` for equations only, but that always leaves me with spacing issues before and after equations, plus, I am not sure if this will look good with multiline equations if the rest of the document is `onehalfspacing`. I'd really like to select `onehalfspacing` once and for all, just the look of (big) matrices bothers me...
- I stumbled across package `nicematrix`, hoping it would give me more parameters for tweaking, but with little success.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Real quick: Why are you using the low-level parameter `\linespread`, given that you're using the `setspace` package? The main point (or possibly even the whole point) point of the `setspace` package is to free users from having to modify such low-level parameters. Also, please provide more information about the "alleged solutions" which you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only sensible solution is to adjust `\arraystretch` to the inverse of `\baselinestretch`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{setspace}
% actually I'd like to use \onehalfspacing, but again,
% a bigger stretch makes the problem more clear
\setstretch{3} 
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0.33333}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Spacing the matrix is simply absurd, in my opinion.

Something like the following is as ugly as the “asymmetric” version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{setspace}
% actually I'd like to use \onehalfspacing, but again,
% a bigger stretch makes the problem more clear
\setstretch{3} 

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
\noalign{\kern-0.3\ht\strutbox}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\onehalfspacing`, first version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8} % \baselinestretch is 1.25

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Second version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
\noalign{\kern-0.15\ht\strutbox}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You decide.

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for your "inverse" hint when working with `\arraystretch`. For the alternative version, is there also some kind of logic behind the numbers you chose? Sorry, I'm not that familiar with the primitives you are using. Even if you find it ugly, I will hold onto it as a backup.

Comment: @17tmh Visual formatting